# How to TRUNCATE tables and DROP child tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Command

```sql
SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE tableowner = 'user' AND schemaname = 'metrics' AND tablename != 'alembic_version';
```

return for example

```
metrics.interaction
metrics.interaction_2023_08_03t00
metrics.traffic
metrics.traffic_2023_08_04t00
metrics.traffic_2023_08_06t00
```

how to make a query to TRUNCATE the parent tables and DROP the successor tables without using regular expressions

Expected result

```
metrics.interaction

metrics.traffic

// and another only parent tables
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want something like:

```
SELECT p.tablename AS to_truncate, array_agg(s.name) AS to_drop
  FROM pg_tables AS p 
  JOIN pg_tables AS s ON
       s.tableowner = 'user' AND
       s.schemaname = 'metrics' AND
       s.name LIKE (p.name || '_%')
 WHERE p.tableowner = 'user' AND
       p.schemaname = 'metrics' AND
       p.tablename != 'alembic_version'
 GROUP BY 1
```